# Work-Location translated to french

Tags: bug, jobs, localization

A while ago I set up the places I want to work. Today I looked at my Profile, and it seems, that one entry (Lansing, MI) has the text "États-Unis" next to it, I belive that's french for USA.
The other Entries look fine:

[image]

Same goes for the Preview of my CV.

My Browser is `Firefox 47.0`, and this is the Value of my `Accept-Language` Header:
`de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3`

Comment: posted on meta.so: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326942/work-location-translated-to-french